# How to update div color dynamically everythime php function is re-run in html page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to have a div which will show the server status with green or red background color.
The background color should change when the php function sets a $status variable to green or red, which will be used in the div to set the background-color parameter!
This is working when I reload the webpage but I would like to run the php function in intervals and update the color of the div field automatically without reloading the webpage.

See what I have till now:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<h1>Measurements - graphs</h1>
<?php
function getStatus() {
    $status = "#008000";
    $latestFile = '/my/web/logs/logging_rotation.out';
    
    if (file_exists($latestFile)) {
        $fileTime = filectime($latestFile);
        $now = microtime(true);
        $timediff = $now - $fileTime;
    }
    if ($timediff < 60) {
            $status = "#008000";
    } else {
        $status = "#FF0000";
    }
    return $status;
}   
?>
<div style="height: 20px; background-color: <?php echo getStatus()?>;">
Server status
</div>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So, what I miss now is a way to run php getStatus in intervals and that should update the background-color and it should update the div field. Is there a way to do that?

After some first suggestions I modified my code to:

```
<script>
    console.log('Starting doSomething'); // test printout
    async function doSomething() {
        const url = "status.php";
        await fetch(
            url,
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: new URLSearchParams("function=serverStatus")
            }
        )
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response); // printout response
            document.getElementById('serverStatus').style.backgroundColor = response; //set the response from the php function as the background color
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('s/g went wrong', err));
    }
</script>
<script>
    setInterval(doSomething, 1000);
</script>
<div id="serverStatus" style="height: 20px;">Server status</div>
```

But, it seems that the `doSomething()` is not executed because I don't see any of the `console.log` printouts!

All the above page is saved as mypage.php and I test this in two ways:

1. reload the mypage.php in a browser.
2. execute the mypage.php via php command:

> php mypage.php > test.html

In both cases I don't get any of the printouts in `doSomething()`.

Is this the correct way to test this kind of php pages?

Update after some further tries and now it works, no changes in the status.php, the issue was the path to status.php:

```
<script>
    async function doSomething() {
        const url = "/status.php"; // this is the correct path
        await fetch(
            url,
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: new URLSearchParams("function=serverStatus")
            }
        )
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            document.getElementById('serverStatus').style.backgroundColor = response; //set the response from the php function as the background color
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('s/g went wrong', err));
    };
    setInterval('doSomething()', 1000); // correct call of doSomething()
</script>
<h2>Measurements - graphs</h2>
<div id="serverStatus" style="height: 20px;">Server status</div>
```

Both below answers and solutions are working!
Regarding the second solution I modified it to:

```
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
    fetch('/status.php').then(response=>response.text()).then(function(text){
      document.getElementById('serverStatus').style.backgroundColor = text;
    })
  }, 1000) // in milliseconds
</script>
<h2>Measurements - graphs</h2>
<div id="serverStatus" style="height: 20px;">Server status</div>
```

status.php:

```
<?php
    $status = "#008000";
    $latestFile = '/my/web/logs/logging_rotation.out';
    if (file_exists($latestFile)) {
        $fileTime = filectime($latestFile);
        $now = microtime(true);
        $timediff = $now - $fileTime;
    }
    if ($timediff < 60) {
        $status = "#008000";
    } else {
        $status = "#FF0000";
    }
    exit($status); //return the result to the JS
?>
```

I do like both solutions, because one is using asynchronous programming and the other one is really compact! I guess in my case the asynchronous programming has more a knowledge benefit then actually for my website and just checking if my server is still up & running by checking if the elapsed time of last modification of the log file is under 60s.

Thanks again

Comment: The simplest approach would be AJAX. See the [beginner's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) or perhaps the [jQuery version](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). If you need to run this in rather short intervals, you might want to research websockets instead.

Answer (score 3):

You will need 2 javascript functions.

1. setTimeout()
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval
   This will call a function at an interval
2. fetch()
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
   This
   make an http call to the server

Example

```
<script>
var myDiv = document.getElementById('serverStatus');
  setInterval(function() {
    fetch('status.php').then(response=>response.text()).then(function(text){
      myDiv.style.backgroundColor = text;
    })
  }, 1000) // in milliseconds
</script>
```

or if you are feeling adventurous:

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById('serverStatus');
setInterval(async () =>
  myDiv.style.backgroundColor = await (await fetch('status.php')).text(),
  1000 // ms
);
```

your status.php only needs to return the color code

Comment: Actually I have the same issue with this solution like the one from Daniel82. It seems like the status.php is never executed!?

Comment: The HTML in your example is broken. This might be the reason javascript is not executed. The `<head>` tag is only for headers you have to add html structure into the `<body>` tag. Make sure the `<script>` tag is just before closing the body (`</body>`) Then press F12 in the browser to open the developer panel and check the "network" tab to see if requests are being made to "status.php".

Comment: I got it running, it was the path to status.php not correct it needed `/`. I have updated my question.

Comment: I am glad you got it working. Don't use async because `setTimeout()` isn't using the return value of its callback. You could await the `fetch()` and `text()` functions to get rid of the `then()` blocks. I'll add an example. See MDN to learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using javascript.

Add an ID to your `<div>`, lets say `<div id="serverStatus" style="height: 20px; background-color: <?php echo getStatus()?>;">`, and then add a timed function to a `<script>` section at the bottom:

```
<script>
    setInterval(doSomething, 5000); // Time in milliseconds 
</script>
```

Then create the js for calling the PHP function and updating the background color:

```
<script>
    async function doSomething() {
        await fetch('myPhpFile.php', { 
            method: "POST", 
            body: new URLSearchParams("function=serverStatus")
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
            document.getElementById('serverStatus').style.backgroundColor = response; //set the response from the php function as the background color
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('s/g went wrong', err));
    }
</script>
```

This will use the Fetch API to run a function in a PHP file called "myPhpFile.php".
I formulated this as below, using your PHP from above and only adding checks to see that this is the function you are calling:

```
<?php
    If(isset($_POST['function'])) { //checks that the parameter function is set
        if($_POST['function']=="serverStatus") { //checks that this is the function asked for
            $status = "#008000";
            $latestFile = '/my/web/logs/logging_rotation.out';
    
            if (file_exists($latestFile)) {
                $fileTime = filectime($latestFile);
                $now = microtime(true);
                $timediff = $now - $fileTime;
            }
            if ($timediff < 60) {
                $status = "#008000";
            } else {
                $status = "#FF0000";
            }
            exit($status); //return the result to the JS
        }
    }
?>
```

I'll note that I have not tested the PHP function you are using to get the filetime, but the javascript is one that is in use, as well as the basic model of the php.

Comment: Seems actually straight forward but I did used it and it seems like it never executes the myPhpFile.php and the `<div>` remains with default background color (white). One question, in the `<div>` part do I miss something? For now I have `<div id="serverStatus" style="height: 20px">Server status</div>`. I removed the php part `<?php echo getStatus()?>` since now this should be taking over from the `doSomething()` correct!?

Comment: Your div looks good to me. Yes, the `doSomething` is now taking over for the PHP function. Check if the "myPhpFile.php" in the same directory as the file which has the page. If not, modify the `await fetch('myPhpFile.php'`, as this should be the address, i.e. if myPhpFile.php is in a sub-folder, that needs to be reflected here. You could put in a `console.log(response)` just before the `document.getElementById('serverStatus').style.backgroundColor = response;` line, to see if you are getting any response from the file.

Comment: I observed that it doesn't execute the `doSomething()` function. I did put in several places `console.log` at the beginning and at the point you suggested and neither of the `console.log` printouts are printed!v I have updated my code till now.